# Only echo item in foreach with highest value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I am trying to get the highest number from a set of SKUs in WordPress. I have the below code which gets a list of all SKUs. I am then only showing the ones which contain the string `'BUR'` and then I am using `explode` to trim the output. Based on the below what is the best method?

Example Data:

```
ABB-0001-1
ABB-0002-1
ABB-0003-1
BUR-0001-1
BUR-0002-1
BUR-0003-1
```

Current Code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product'), 
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$wcProductsArray = get_posts($args);

if (count($wcProductsArray)) {
    foreach ($wcProductsArray as $productPost) {
        $productSKU = get_post_meta($productPost->ID, '_sku', true);
        $productTitle = get_the_title($productPost->ID);
            if (strpos($productSKU, 'BUR') !== false) { 
                $s = explode("-",$productSKU);
                echo '<li>' . $s[1] . '</li>';
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Current Output:

```
0003
0002
0001
```

Desired Output:

```
0003
```

Comment: Just keep track of the maximum as you loop, and then echo it _after_ the loop.

Comment: How can I keep track of the maximum if the loop is actually BUR-0001-1? I have had to modify the output to get just the 4 numbers. So I'm not sure how to sort and filter when it contains the letters and 2 number sets

Comment: Just add a `break` statement in the `if (strpos($productS...` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking of something like this to keep track of the maximum:

```
// initialize $max before the loop
$max = null;

foreach ($wcProductsArray as $productPost) {
    $productSKU = get_post_meta($productPost->ID, '_sku', true);
    $productTitle = get_the_title($productPost->ID);
        if (strpos($productSKU, 'BUR') !== false) { 
            $s = explode("-",$productSKU);

            // update $max as you loop
            $max = max($max, $s[1]);
        }
}
// print it afterward
echo $max;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: I have added some extra code. I would like to keep the full 4digit number however when adding to it I lose the '0'. 

`echo $max; // echos 0001
$newSkuNumber = $max + 1; // need to add 1 to max
$newSKU = $skuPrefix . '-' . $newSkuNumber . '-1'; // need to complete the new SKU
echo $newSKU; // echo new SKU. output is BUR-2-1 should be BUR-0002-1`

Comment: When you add to it, PHP converts it to an integer. You can use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to pad it with zeroes again.